# Titanium Alloy - How the application run when dialog created?

Tags: titanium

I have this code in Titanium:

```
a;
showDialog({
        title: L('dialog_title_geo_error'), 
        message: L("alert_geo_disable")
    });
b;
function showDialog(args) {
  var dialog =  Ti.UI.createAlertDialog(args);
  dialog.show();
  return dialog;  
};
```

After run showDialog(); what is the behaviour of the app? Will it pause there or continue to run to b; ?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you use only alert() function then app will get executed in background it will not wait for alert() function response.

But if you create alert message with Ti.UI.createAlertDialog() and event listener for it then app will wait for response from users input .

ref:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog-property-cancel

In this page example 1 and 2 are like don't wait for execution and if you use example 3 and use appropriate event as per your requirement then you can achieve it.